# how to configure a chat of whatapp with laravel app and twilio

Tags: laravel, api, twilio, whatsapp, twilio-programmable-chat

I'm trying to create a sandbox chat with [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) with la-ravel using whats-app but unfortunately i found i cant handle to consume the [whats-app twilio API](https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp) for whats-app and use it am a bit good in la-ravel but not much in API please help

i want to send my message to the user that has subscribed to my whats-app number given by twilio and let the user be able to reply so i can get the message back

Comment: Can you please provide some code that you have already tried, along with any errors you have received from it. If this is more of a 'how to' question, then Stack Overflow is not the correct place to be asking for assistance.

Comment: Yes i have tried using the Twilio package for la-ravel and i ending up getting error on usage of undefined constant CURLOPT_URL then i added the la-ravel curl package but seems like error still persist that is why i decided to find a new way may be a can lean to,